# Sorting algorithm 2

Tags: sorting

An in-place algorithm with O(n) running time that rearranges an unsorted array A[0 . . . n − 1] filled with distinct integers so that, for a given k (1<=k<=n), A[0 . . . k − 1] contains the k smallest integers in increasing order.

Is there an existing algorithm that meets these specifications, or one that can be altered to meet them?

Comment: yes, partially, the homework requires the implementation of this algorithm but the professor said in class that the algorithm already exists, I just need to know which one it is, then I can study it and implement it, can you help?

Answer (score 2):

If you [google for O(n) sorts](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=O%28n%29+sorting+algorithm&aq=f&aqi=g1g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=a9ec0a8ac5f5a7a2), you would end up with [Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) or [Radix Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).